# VBA issue with a variable

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that "z" needs to be different for the second if-statement. But, if I loop it, it will get stuck and not do what it is supposed to. I need to know how to find a different value of "z" that fits the scenario of the second if-statement. This is what I have so far. Good luck

```
Dim finalrow As Long
finalrow = Worksheets("Redundancy").Cells(Worksheets("Redundancy").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim z As Long
Dim color As Integer
color = 3
Dim smrownumber As Integer
Dim arownumber As Integer
Dim across As Integer
Dim CellA As String
Dim match As String
Dim CellB As String
Dim change As Integer
Dim First As Integer
Dim Second As Integer
Dim FirstLast As Integer
Dim SecondLast As Integer
For z = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(2 + z, 9).Value = Cells(3 + z, 9).Value And Cells(2 + z, 10).Value <> Cells(3 + z, 10).Value Then
        First = z + 2
        FirstLast = First + 1
    End If
    If z <> 2 Then
        If Cells(2 + z, 9).Value = Cells(3 + z, 9).Value And Cells(2 + z, 11).Value <> Cells(3 + z, 11).Value Then
            Second = z + 2
            SecondLast = Second + 1
        End If
        Else
            Second = z + 2
            SecondLast = 2
    End If
        For arownumber = SecondLast To First 'need to find the rownumbers that we compare with
            For change = 4 To 7
                For smrownumber = FirstLast To Second 'need to find the rownumbers for comparing
                    For across = 4 To 7
                        CellA = Cells(arownumber, change)
                        CellB = Cells(smrownumber, across)
                        match = IIf(CellA = CellB, "yes", "no")
                        If match = "yes" Then
                            Cells(arownumber, change).Interior.ColorIndex = color
                            Cells(smrownumber, across).Interior.ColorIndex = color
                            color = color + 1
                        End If
                    Next across
                Next smrownumber
            Next change
        Next arownumber
 Next z
```

Comment: This is unclear. Explain what you mean by ""z" needs to be different for the second if-statement". Different from *what*. Different *how*?

Comment: "Second"'s value should be more than "z" therefore "z" should be larger.

Comment: That doesn't clarify the question. If `z` is the index of a loop variable then it should successively take on all the values between the lower bound and upper bound of the loop. It doesn't really make sense to give a variable a value and then claim that it "should" be something other than what your code instructs it to be. If you don't want to compart a quantity with `z` -- don't. Compare it with something else. Just what, I don't know, since you haven't really explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps you need a `while` loop (where you increment `z` in different ways depending on your conditions) rather than a `for` loop?

Comment: If z needs to be different in some way then perhaps you need two variables instead of trying to use z in two different ways?